# How can I use this complete query with sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to convert this code to sequelize.

```
where ADDTIME(deleted_at, TIMEDIFF(deleted_at, end_at) * 2) > NOW() OR (end_at < NOW() AND deleted_at is null);
```

I found below at sequelize docs. But it is not enough to my query.

```
Post.findAll({
    where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('char_length', 
    sequelize.col('status')), 6)
});
```

I want to convert this code to sequelize.

```
where ADDTIME(deleted_at, TIMEDIFF(deleted_at, end_at) * 2) > NOW() OR (end_at < NOW() AND deleted_at is null);
```

like this. I don't want to use RAW Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of this clause is simple to express in Sequelize, shown below:

```
where : {
     [Op.or] : [
          // 1
          Sequelize.where(
                Sequelize.fn('ADDTIME', 
                    Sequelize.col('deleted_at'), 
                    Sequelize.literal('TIMEDIFF(deleted_at, end_at) * 2')),
                {[Op.gt] : Sequelize.fn('NOW')}
          ),
          // 2
          {
                 end_at      : { [Op.lt]: Sequelize.fn('NOW') },
                 deleted_at  : null
          }
     ]
}
```

The only sticky point is the multiplication - not sure how/if there is a way to do this without a literal....

HTH